# AngularJS - refactor code to Service/Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am need to refactor some code and convert it into a factory/service calls. This was the original code being cslled for an autocomplete dropdown.

```
$scope.querySearchManagerName = function (skill) {
    console.log(skill);
    //var entry = skill.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase()

    var query = {
      "managerName" : skill
    }
    if(skill.length < 2){
        return [query]
    }
    else{
        return $http.post('/tdp/managerTypeahead/', query)
        .then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
        })
        .catch(function(reason) {
          $scope.genericError();
          }
        )
    }
}
```

The factory code I have converted to is :

```
var querySearchManagerName = function(skill) {
   var query = {
      "managerName" : skill
   }
   return $http.post('/tdp/managerTypeahead/', query)
     .then(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
      $scope.genericError();
      }
    )
}
```

And calling of the factory is :

```
$scope.querySearchManagerName = function (skill) {
    console.log(skill);
   //var entry = skill.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase()

   var query = {
     "managerName" : skill
   }
   if(skill.length < 2){
       return [query]
   }
   else{
    return $scope.demandFactory.querySearchManagerName(skill);
   }
 }
```

However I am getting an error :

> TypeError: $scope.demandFactory.querySearchManagerName is not a function.

Any clue why i am getting it?

Comment: I am surprised that there is no injection error. Factories can't inject $scope.

Comment: how can i remove the error?